# How to disable cache with manifest in html?

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache

I've added manifest to my html:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# rev ?v=1

NETWORK:
*
```

It works fine when I am trying to load page for the first time - it shows me the total transfer in my dev tools of 1mb. However, for the second time, it shows me only 100kb's. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: use this <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />

Comment: or check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: @PardeepPathania, I've tried the cache manifest, however, as I can see in chrome developers, after first page loading, it shows me 1mb, but then its always 100kb (seems like its caching), am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that in *Network* tabs of the *Developer Tools* of your browser.
First make sure **Disable cache** is **disabled**.

In *Network* tab you'll see `(from cache)` in the column `Size` if a file was taken from cache.

Comment: so, if disable cahce is enabled, all meta tags are overwritten, otherwise, it takes the behaviour descibred in head of html?

Comment: and actually, if I disable 'disable cache' all of the files have same size of ~244b

Comment: **Disable cache* is a parameter is Developer tools. You have to disable it so Developer tools don't affect caching behavior of your browser. If you enable the parameter the browser will never use cache (always reload all files from server), so you won't be able to check if browser uses cache or not.